# Take an image and save it on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am looking for a tutorial where i can take a picture using my iPhone and save it on the phone. I googled this but was not able to find any tutorial or sample code to begin with. Can someone please help me by pointing out a tutorial or sample code?

Comment: What did you google for, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code for the Taking Image

```
UIPicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:UIPicker animated:YES];
```

## Successful capture of image

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage  *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {


    //code to save image in gallary
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(receivedImage, nil,nil, nil);

     //close the picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

## Failure in capture of image

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
     //close the picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to `UIImagePickerController`
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Answer (score 2):

For getting image by camera see this articles:

[Camera Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/)

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)